# Usage of {{ and {% in django?

Tags: python, html, django

In `views.py` I passed `'key_tp_list': tb_list,'key_tb_list': tb_list`. Their type is dictionay list. Then in my html, I wrote :

```
{% for i in range(key_tp_length) %}
    <li>{{ key_tp_list[i].eid }} | {{ dict.user }} | {{ dict.start_time }} | {{ dict.note }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And it turned out to have 2 errors : I can't use a `range(key_tp_length)` in `{% %}`, neither I can use a `key_tp_list[i]` in `{{ }}`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Share your errors please

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over a range *anyway*. Always iterate over the thing itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use complex expressions in Django `{{ }}` tags, but assuming `key_tp_length` is the length of `key_tp_list`, you can do:

```
    {% for item in key_tp_list %}
        <li>{{ item.eid }} | {{ item.user }} | {{ item.start_time }} | {{ item.note }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And that is exactly what I wrote. But I would like to make the list shown like this:  <li>{{ item_from_tp_list.eid }} | {{ item_from_tp_list.user }} ....</li> <li>{{ item_from_tb_list.eid }} | {{ item_from_tb_list.user }} ....</li>, how could I achieve this?

Comment: In "parallel" from the two lists? I'd suggest `zip`ing them in your view before passing them to the template: `tp_tb_pairs = zip(tp_list, tb_list)`, and then you can iterate over that list with `{% for tp_item, tb_item in tp_tb_pairs %}`.